# How to Navigate through all Positions and get the Type of them in MQL5

Tags: mql5, metatrader5

```
for(int i=0; i<PositionsTotal(); i++)
           {

             string id=PositionGetString(POSITION_COMMENT);
           int type = PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE);
```

I have an Expert Advisor that I want to get the type of Positions and navigate through the information of Positions  .... this two lines of code does not work for me the don't return value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to select the position before calling `PositionGetDouble()`, `PositionGetInteger()`, `PositionGetString()` functions.

You can select a position by `PositionSelect()` in netting accounts and also by calling the function `PositionGetTicket()` it returns the ticket number and also select the current positions (but this is unreliable). You can also use `PositionSelectByTicket()` if you know the ticket number.

> To ensure that you always get fresh set of data, it is recommended to call the `PositionSelectByTicket()` after getting the ticket from `PositionGetTicket()` function, before calling `PositionGetDouble()`, `PositionGetInteger()`, and `PositionGetString()` functions.

Here is an example, it prints the position type and its ticket.

```
for(int i = PositionsTotal() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      ulong ticket = PositionGetTicket(i);
      if(ticket>0){
          PositionSelectByTicket(ticket);
          ENUM_POSITION_TYPE posType = PositionGetInteger(POSITION_TYPE);
          Print(EnumToString(posType) + " : " + (string)ticket);
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi Sir, could you please assist me with the following MQL5 question I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62479581/how-to-search-for-a-candlestick-pattern-on-multiple-timeframes